# List Arrayadapter not showing Anything

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am parsing XML and trying to propagate it in list view.

I am using Following code

Main Activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> xmlList=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> xmlList1=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try{
        InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);

        DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc=builder.parse(is, null);

        NodeList nodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("id");
        NodeList nodes1=doc.getElementsByTagName("Name");

        if(nodes!=null && nodes.getLength() >0)
        {
            xmlList.clear();
            xmlList1.clear(); 
            int len=nodes.getLength();

            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                Node node=nodes.item(i);
                Node node1=nodes1.item(i);
                xmlList.add(node.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    CustomList adapter=new CustomList(MainActivity.this,xmlList,xmlList1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> mainText;
private final ArrayList<String> subText1;

public CustomList(Context context, ArrayList<String> mainText, ArrayList<String>  subText1) {
    super(context,R.layout.custumlist);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=context;
    this.mainText=mainText;
    this.subText1=subText1;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custumlist, null);

    TextView main=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    TextView sub1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subText1);

    main.setText(mainText.toString());
    sub1.setText(subText1.toString());
    return view;
}
```

}

But it is not showing anything nor posting any log cat.
I think there is something wrong inside infliating the View. Minor problem but not able to find. Please help me in that.

Thnx

Comment: overwrite getCount() in your adapter and return your list's size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your CustomList put below code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mainText.size();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Override the `getCount` method in your `CustomList`

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
  return mainText.size();
}
```

OR

change the `super` call in `CustomList` constructor from

```
super(context, R.layout.custumlist);
```

to

```
super(context, R.layout.custumlist,mainText);
```